# Concavity/ Convexity of power means function?

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, contest-math, convexity-inequality

Let $a_i > 0$ forall $1 \leq i \leq n$ and let $M(x) :=  \big(\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^x}{n} \big)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ be the power means function. It is well known that the power means function is non-decreasing.

I am interested in the concavity properties of $M(x)$ but checking if $M''(x) \geq 0$ seems to be too difficult.

I was able to compute $M''(x)$. Let $M(x) = f(x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ where $f(x) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^x}{n}$. Then I was able to find:
$$
\frac{M''(x) f^2(x)}{\big(\frac{M(x)}{x^4} \big)} = (xff' - f \ln f)^2 + x^3(ff'' - f'^2) - 2x(xff' - f^2 \ln f)
 $$
where $'$ denotes derivative and number denotes powers. Checking the sign of $M''(x)$ is equivalent to the checking the sign of the RHS. This terms seem too hard to check for positivity. Can anyone help? I know for a fact that $M(x)$ is convex and concave on different intervals, but I can't find these intervals. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by canonical answer?

Comment: In the equation for $M''$, the first term in RHS should be $(xf' - f \ln f)^2$. It seems difficult to find the exact intervals? Can we prove that $M''(x) < 0$ for $x > x_0$ for some $x_0\ge 1$?

Comment: @SomeGuy I meant just find the answer for upto the 3 variable case (unfortunately MSE gives a list of options which I can tick from, and the nearest to "find the answer" was "find the canonical answer", hence I ticked that.

Comment: @RiverLi If you can give me the value of $x_0$, that would helpful (I would accept it). However an answer like "$\exists x_0$, where .... " wouldn't be so helpful.

Comment: One possible way to find the intervals could be to equate the triple derivative to 0, to get the inflection points.

Comment: @Kaind Why did you choose the tag [contest-math] ?
I'd guess it makes sense to replace the former by [convex-analysis]  and possibly
[convexity-inequality] .

Comment: A good source might also be Ladislav Matejíčka: Short note on convexity of power mean

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285385599_Short_note_on_convexity_of_power_mean

Comment: @Hanno If you find $M(x)$ to be convex/ concave on some interval, applying Jensen's to it, solves nearly half of all contest maths problems in one shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All this is complicated.

---

Too complicated $-$ consider alone $M''(x)=\ldots\;$
And paired with the resulting nescience, this excludes a canonical answer.

**It is known that**

- if $n=2$ and $a_1\neq a_2$, then $M(x)$ possesses one inflection point (not necessarily at $x=0$). On the left of it, $M(x)$ is convex. And concave to the right of it.
  See [Nam & Minh: "Proof for a Conjecture on General means"](http://emis.matem.unam.mx/journals/JIPAM/images/163_08_JIPAM/163_08_www.pdf)
  (J of Inequalities in Pure & Applied Math., Vol. 9, 2008)
- if $n=3$, then more inflection points may pop up.
  A concrete instance having three inflection points (albeit in the weighted context) was proposed by [Grant Keady](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/370_05_JIPAM/370_05.pdf) , cf the first paragraph on page 2 of "Conjecture on General means"
  (J of Inequalities in Pure & Applied Math., Vol. 7, 2006).

The questions are as intriguing as old, you may also
[read H. Shniad](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1948-54-08/S0002-9904-1948-09077-2/S0002-9904-1948-09077-2.pdf), published 73 years ago
(Bulletin Amer. Math. Soc. 54, pp 770$-$776, 1948).

Comment: The first paper is a good insight.

Comment: Nice references.